# Switching off Magnetic Field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, magnetic-fields

> A line charge (charge per unit length 'k') is put onto rim of wheel of radius 'R' which is then suspended horizontally, so that its free to rotate (spokes are made of non conducting material). In the central region upto radius 'r' there is uniform magnetic field 'B' pointing up. Now someone turns field off. Moment of Inertia of wheel with the spokes is 'I'.
>
> Find an expression for angular speed of wheel after magnetic field is switched off. Also explain origin of angular speed.

Comment: Where is your attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't give you the complete answer. But here is how you should start off.

You must be aware of Maxwell's equations. We know that a changing magnetic field will induce an electric field. Since the wheel given in your question has a linear charge density, it should feel a force due to the induced electric field. This force will in turn produce the torque which provides an angular acceleration, hence angular speed.

But you should be clever, instead of taking all the trouble by using forces , you can smartly make use of conservation of energy to solve the problem. (Hint: There is some energy stored in the magnetic flux)

You can solve using the force method too, I solved and its pretty simple.

You have to use Maxwell's equation,

$ \int E.dl =d\phi/dt $

You have to use symmetry and say that the field remains constant every where around the loop. Hence, you can easily evaluate the integral and find the field.

The total force on the ring would be,

$dF =Edq$

$\int Edq = F$

From here you can find the torque, the last step would be to substitute for E from Maxwell's equation in the torque equation. You can now calculate the angular impulse provided by the force on the ring.

$J = \int \tau dt $

The equation which you obtained for torque will be having the rate of change of flux, solving the simple differential equation, you should obtain the answer for angular impulse. The rest of course, you must be knowing, equate it to the angular momentum of the object(Angular Impulse = change in angular momentum) to obtain the angular velocity.